# Lvalue reference binding

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

I have a question about wording in `N3797::8.5.3/5 [dcl.init.ref]`:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the
>   initializer expression
>
> - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and
>     “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,” or
> - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2,
>     and can be converted to an lvalue of type “cv3 T3,” where “cv1 T1” is
>     reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”

Does the second case mean the initializer expression is a `class`-type as well as an `lvalue`?

Comment: It must have a class type. [Not necessarily an lvalue.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcc01537970ee89a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clause says:

> has a class type

so it must be a *class type*. The examples further down in the document show it does not have to be an *lvalue* though, taking selected parts of the code example we have:

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { operator int&(); } b;

int& ir = B(); // ir refers to the result of B::operator int&
```

`B()` is not a *lvalue* but as `8.5.3/5` says:

> can be converted to an lvalue of type “cv3 T3,” where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3”

which in this case applies.